# Select dropdown does not work properly inside display toggle element in Firefox

Tags: jquery, css, firefox

The select doropdown does not work in dropdown navigation in Firefox.

I have been trying to select an option of select dropdown which is inside a div which gets hidden on mouse leave. Dropdown works fine in chrome but does not work properly in Firefox.

When we leave mouse form div it gets hidden. I have used jQuery to show/hide the div. Select dropdown is inside the div but as soon as click the select dropdown and try to select any option the div gets hidden. It happens only in Firefox other browsers are fine. It seems a browser bug but I am not sure. Can you please advise me if there is any way to fix this issue?

Here is the example code.

```
<ul>
  <li>Toggle Div
    <div class='toggle' style='display:none'>
      <select>
        <option>Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 2</option>
        <option>Option 3</option>
        <option>Option 4</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('document').ready(function(){
$('li').mouseenter(function(){
    $('div.toggle').show();
});
$('li').mouseleave(function(){
    $('div.toggle').hide();
});
});
</script>
```

Here is https://jsfiddle.net/dhiru/5xoshn9w/ jsfiddle url.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mouseenter, mouseleave in Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13359545/mouseenter-mouseleave-in-firefox)